# How can I tell emacs to not split the window on M-x compile or elisp compilation error?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I perform <kbd>M-x compile</kbd> or get an elisp compilation error, my emacs splits the window vertically, and displays the compile output/error message in the new window. I prefer to work with my buffers in a full screen window, because the vertically split window is too narrow for me. Can I tell emacs to *not* split the window and do a <kbd>M-x switch-buffer</kbd> to the compilation/error buffer?

*Edit*: Trey's suggestion works for compilation. Is there a way to set it for all the commands which split the window? The three I have in mind are elisp compiling, <kbd>M-x apropos</kbd> and <kbd>M-x occur</kbd>.

Comment: If this is rephrased as an *elisp* question, it should be on-topic.

Comment: @Arafangion I believe it falls under the `software tools commonly used by programmers` section in the FAQ as is.  There are lots of questions about editors on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(setq compilation-window-height 1000)
```

You could get fancy and actually calculate the number of lines of text in the frame... `(/ (frame-pixel-height) (frame-char-height))`, but that seems silly.

Io control how Emacs generally displays buffers, you can configure the variable `same-window-regexps` to match all buffer names, and then all commands that display buffers using `display-buffer` will use the same window:

```
(setq same-window-regexps '("."))
```

See [Choosing a Window](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Choosing-Window.html) for more details.

Comment: that worked! but is there a way to do it for M-x occur or M-x apropos?

Comment: For `M-x compile`, use: `M-x customize-variable RET same-window-regexps RET` and add the regex `\*compilation\*`

Answer (score 4):

my guess is that you want to customize the `split-window-preferred-function` variable.  the default value is `split-window-sensibly`.  you should change it to a custom version which just switches the current buffer.

this seems to work:

```
(defun no-split-window ()
  (interactive)
  nil)

(setq split-window-preferred-function 'no-split-window)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for compilation windows.  If there are no errors or warnings, it will display the compilation output buffer for a second and then kill it.  Otherwise the buffer stays because you probably want find the errors and fix them.  I got this from [a newsgroup](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2010-11/msg00150.html).

```
(defun kill-compile-buffer-if-successful (buffer string) 
  " kill a compilation buffer if succeeded without warnings " 
  (if (and 
       (string-match "compilation" (buffer-name buffer)) 
       (string-match "finished" string) 
       (not 
        (with-current-buffer buffer 
          (search-forward "warning" nil t)))) 
      (run-with-timer 1 nil 
                      'kill-buffer 
                      buffer)))
(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'kill-compile-buffer-if-successful)
```